React onTouch and onMouse triggering together
We have a library which was developed by a third-party for use along with app which use this library. The library is providing type for different components and layouts:
type FooterIconButtonType = typeof FooterIconButtonInt;

export const FooterIconButton: FooterIconButtonType = (props: ComponentProps<FooterIconButtonType>) => {
  return (
    <FooterIconButtonInt {...props} onClick={undefined} onMouseDown={props.onClick} onTouchStart={props.onClick} />
  );
};

The main app then uses this to trigger button actions:
<FooterButtonsWrapper center style={{zIndex: 2, position: 'relative'}}>
  <FooterIconButton hide={isGrid} src={AppIcons.backSmall} onClick={handlePrevious} />

This triggers a function:
  const handlePrevious = useCallback(() => {
//do some stuff here!!
  }, []);

However what I'm getting is both the onMouse and onTouch trigger at the same time so in effect double pressing causing the function to fire twice.
I have tried adding preventDefault() and stopProagation() into the function code and I've also made two separate functions as intermediary to the handlePrevious function. In effect causing onMouse and onTouch to call different functions then move to handlePrevious but placing the above commands to stop propgation but this makes no difference. If I remove one or the other on event then it reverts to a single press action.
I'm a little rusty on React and I might be missing something obvious here :/

The issue is that both of those events are (intentionally) fired via independent logic in the browser.  If you look carefully at the spec for them, you'll see that that is meant to be.
I would strongly suggest not acting on individual mouseDown and touchStart events and just use onClick.  This is usually adequate unless you're doing something more complex like building a drag-n-drop component manually.

Thanks - for the reply.
Yes I'm aware they are both fired independently, but the issue we have had with the onClick route we seem to not get reliability on touch screens specifically. Mouse interaction is fine but touch seems to be more hit and miss using onClick. The reason why the original developer added this solution as a way of mitigation but it wasn't fully tested due to reasons outside their control at the time.
My understanding is preventDefault is the way to stop the secondary firing but that doesn't seem to be working as aforementioned in the post.

Prevendefault and stopnotification will prevent further events in the same tree for the event type.  The independence means that will not work in your case.
As far as touch, I’ve never heard of onClick being an issue in touch device or requiring a workaround.  (I often develop for mobile and handle such issues)
One thing to not is that onClick is triggered on the release. Perhaps there was some confusion there?

To clarify further, I should emphasize the for the event type... (NOT say, for all related events that originate with a common interface gesture).  It would be lovely if it worked that way, but it doesn't.  Think of the raw mouse / pointer event as starting several chains of events all at once for several event types. .... preventDefault() will prevent further processing of that event for that type ... such as a button onClick, or handling in the parent.  But the "related" events are still in the queue and cannot be prevented from a handler for a different event type.
